# sharepoint fast-search(FQL) querytext for sharepoint people search

Tags: fast-search, web-services

I am new in sharepoint 2010 and I want to make a FQL query For People search

One other thing in sharepoint search MSSQLFt works fine But in fast-search Some fields are not search.Like Department and WorkPhone

Here is my MSSQLFT query demo.

```
  <QueryPacket Revision='1000'><Query><SupportedFormats><Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document</Format></SupportedFormats><ResultProvider>SharepointSearch</ResultProvider><Context><QueryText type='MSSQLFT' language='en-us'>SELECT PREFERREDNAME,FirstName,AboutMe,LastName,JobTitle,Department,Email,WorkEmail,WorkPhone,Skills,PictureUrl,Path,Rank,MobilePhone,Title FROM scope() where \"SCOPE\"='"+scope+"' AND ((\"JobTitle\" = '" + lastName + "') OR (\"WorkPhone\" = '" + lastName + "') OR (\"Skills\" = '" + lastName + "') OR (\"LastName\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"FirstName\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"Department\" = '" + lastName + "') OR (\"WorkEmail\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%')  OR  (\"PreferredName\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"AboutMe\" = '" + lastName + "'))</QueryText></Context><Range><StartAt>1</StartAt><Count>10</Count></Range><EnableStemming>true</EnableStemming><TrimDuplicates>true</TrimDuplicates><IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>true</IgnoreAllNoiseQuery><ImplicitAndBehavior>true</ImplicitAndBehavior><IncludeRelevanceResults>true</IncludeRelevanceResults><IncludeSpecialTermResults>true</IncludeSpecialTermResults><IncludeHighConfidenceResults>true</IncludeHighConfidenceResults></Query></QueryPacket>
```

So please help me what is the difference between fast-search and sharepoint search.
If possible give me some FQL query Example

Comment: In SharePoint you need to configure fields the crawler indexes. Is there similar setting in FAST?

Comment: Jussi palo thanks for your reply I found My solution.
I found my solution just go to central admin>Services>search service>menaged Property find your field Edit them and select option  "Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAST is not used for People Search (it's queried through the normal SPS SSA), so you cannot use FQL in this case.

Comment: hi Wictor-Now my query is works fine.
My other problem is I am not able to query in where clause Like
 where (\"AboutMe\" = '%" + lastName + "%')
but (\"AboutMe\" = '" + lastName + "') it works fine for me
This problem i face in other fields Department,jobtitle,Skills

Comment: I found my solution just go to central admin>Services>search service>menaged Property find your field Edit them and select option  "Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison"

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for composing FQL queries: [FAST search form SharePoint](http://fastforsharepoint.codeplex.com/)
And there is [the reference of FQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff394606.aspx).